# Sunspot Search with Multiple Types vs. Single Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

What are the pros and cons of Sunspot Search with Multiple Types vs Single Type? What is the preferred way?

I've looked through a lot of docs and can't seem to find the answers.

- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot
- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki
- http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/rails/docs/index.html
- http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/docs/Sunspot.html#search-class_method

Example of Multiple Type Search:

```
Sunspot.search(Post, Comment) do
  with :blog_id, 1
  fulltext 'hello' do
    fields(:comment_body)
  end
end
```

Example of Single Type Search with association to another Model/Type:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    text :comments do
      comments.map { |comment| comment.body }
    end
end

Post.search do
  fulltext 'hello' do
    fields(:comments)
  end
end
```

It seems I can achieve the same results using either methods (Multiple Types or Single Type).

Answer (score 2):

After heading down the path of multiple type search, let's see if I can provide some answers to my questions.

Cons of Multiple Type Search

- What most people want returned is a homogenous list of results/hits to display. When you do Sunspot.search(Type1, Type2, etc) or Sunspot.search which by default searches all Types, then calling .results gets a mix of data types which makes it harder to display in the view.
- If Post has many Comments and I want to find Posts that have "xyz" in the comments, then Sunspot.search(Comment).results will return a list of comments, not the list of Posts I really want. I can use the post_id in the Comment results/hits to retrieve a list of Posts, but that's a performance hit.
- It's harder to do a Sunspot.search.hits on multiple types to get a list of common fields to display to the view.
- According to http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/rails/docs/index.html, "Sunspot is entirely agnostic about whether searches are for one or more types; the only restriction is that columns used for restriction, ordering, etc. are defined in the same way for all types being searched." The columns have to be defined the sames for all types.

Therefore, Single Type Search with associations and mapping to multiple models, which doesn't have any of these issues and can return the same results easily, is preferred IMHO.

Comment: In any case, seems like more of an application concern (what are the semantics of what the user is searching, and how is that modeled?) rather than a technical question.

Comment: Hi Nick - thank you for making for a comment and your work on sunspot. To answer your questions, a user searches via a form to find a list of matching Posts. There are check boxes in the form that allow the user to search all or some selected fields. Not all fields are attributes of the Post model, some fields are from other models (like the Comment model). The other models are associated to the Post model. For example, Post has_many :comments. So after the user submits the form, it executes a controller's method, which then simply calls a search model method to do the search.

Comment: My questions were just general (Multiple Type vs Single Type Search). However to break it down, 1. Should we put searchable block inside each model, and do Sunspot.search(model1, model2, etc); or should we put searchable block in just one model that the users care about, and use mapping to associate the data between the models. 2. when is Multiple Type search handy? I see a lot of examples on Single Type and rarely any on Multiple Types. Is Multiple Type Search not useful or recommended?